# How detect on tfs if project doesn't change

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I have local TFS2012. How can I detect, If was been any changes in Project or not? I need this variable to decide in powershell script: deploy package on not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmatically you can get the history of the project root using tf.exe:

```
tf history . /stopafter:1 /format:brief /noprompt
```

Note: the '`.`' is just using the current location mapped to a TFS location, you would probably use `$/Some/branch/location` instead of '`.`'

The output will need to be parsed to get the date field

```
Changeset Change                     User              Date       Comment
--------- -------------------------- ----------------- ---------- -------------
375564    merge                      developer    (... 8/24/2010  Merge comment
```

you can get the full set of tf history options by running tf history /?

another way would be to try and get latest, if you get anything there was a change:

```
tf get . /preview /noprompt /recursive
```

returns:

```
Getting somefile.cpp
Getting someotherfile.cs
:
:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look to see if any specific files have changed you can View History of a specific folder and look at the dates on changesets.  This can also be done programmatically using the TFS API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on only generating nuget packages for changed projects so I needed to figure out changed files.  Once you have the changed files you can search for projects that contain (or are) those changed items (files/folders):

. "$tf" diff . /noprompt /format:brief /version:D"$($lastBuildstartTime.ToString())"~W /recursive |? {$_ -like "*only*" -or $_ -like "*differ*"}

Hope that helps!